# Are there still any remains of Flash on YouTube for Chrome?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm working on a Chrome extension and would like to know if there are still any remains of Flash use in videos on Youtube?

When I checked two weeks ago Flash was still in use for live stream, but when I checked today I was happy to see that the live stream is now also using HTML5.

Now I can't take a risk so I would like to know please if there is still any Flash use somewhere in videos in the YouTube world?

I already spent hours of making my extension to work with the Flash player, so I will save it in the side for just in case, and would like to get rid of all that unnecessary code.

Comment: Are you just concerned with videos played at YouTube.com, or also those that are embedded on other sites? If it's the latter, you'll probably encounter a good number of flash embeds, from sites/apps that use the old (deprecated but not yet retired) player APIs.

Comment: Thanks yes I'm only concerned with videos on Youtube.com site itself, but if you also got any info about the iframe(HTML5/Flash)-embed (on Chrome) it will also helps please.

Comment: Also if there is anyway to bring back Flash again just for development it will be helpful (on latest version of Chrome in Youtube site itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flash player has been [officially deprecated as of January 27, 2015](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference).  So as a developer, you really shouldn't use that API anymore.  However, protected videos such as movies or TV shows that use the RTMPE streaming protocol still use the Flash player as a form of DRM.

At the time of writing, the [Ghostbusters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GY8lIFhweV4) movie and [Twister](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSdbE5uxINs) TV series use the Flash player.

Comment: Thanks, it means that Flash is still in use and I will unfortunately continue to support it, thanks for the links to the Flash videos.

Comment: I don't know how much Flash is actually in use for normal videos.  These protected videos can't be embedded or played on mobile.  What exactly does your extension do?

Comment: The extension runs on Youtube.com site itself, so I should support whatever kind of videos there, including the new 360 degree videos, so yes I will leave the Flash support in my code for now and won't remove it until Flash use will be completely gone.