# Why YouTube videos are allowed to be played while flash stuff is forbidden on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api

As far as I know, flash is not supported on iOS. However, it's still possible to watch YouTube videos and they are base on flash. Is there some logic embedded into webView like:

```
if ([url containsDomain:@"youtube.com"]) {

  returns YES;

} else {

  return NO;
}
```

As far as I know, most of those YouTube video libraries for iOS apps use webView and loads video into iFrame. Then why and how it works?

Comment: They have some thing that detects if the device is iOS or not, I think, and give an alternate player if needed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the behavior of a UIWebView.  It's all in YouTube's API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [YouTube iFrame Player API Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters):

> Note: YouTube `<object>` embeds were deprecated on January 27, 2015. Please migrate your applications to the `<iframe>` embeds, which can intelligently use whichever embedded player – HTML (`<video>`) or Flash (`<object>`) – the client supports.

The HTML5 player will load on all devices where supported.  If the HTML5 player can't be loaded for whatever reason (see [Are there still any remains of Flash on YouTube for Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30248503/2415822)), the player will return an error to the client.

Comment: argh I'm writing the same thing :D ...and YouTube (on web) now is based on HTML 5. Bye bye Flash! (yes I hate Flash)